# Is there no documentation for Method in Eigensystem?

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra

There does not appear to be any documentation on how to use `Method` in `Eigensystem`, or at least not in Version 9.0.1 of Mathematica (unless I'm looking in the wrong place). The documentation page for `Eigensystem` just gives a single example of using an Arnoldi shift as

```
Method -> {"Arnoldi", Shift -> -4}
```

and the internal implementation page at `tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation#5107` just says that `Eigensystem` uses an ARPACK Arnoldi solver for iterative computing of the first $k$ eigenvectors.

The documentation page on `Method` likewise makes no mention of what options are available for use in eigendecomposition problems. Is there any documentation on what possible syntax options are available for `Method` in the context of `Eigensystem`?

Comment: One of my big complaints about the Mathematica documentation is that the Method option of various functions is typically documented only in a very limited way.  [Enough information to make me interested, but not enough information to make it usable.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/204934?p_p_auth=MLYjo9jS)  However, I have good news for you in this case: [the v10 documentation has added a nice description of the possible method options of Eigenvalues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html).  You'll have to try if these work in v9.

Answer (score 6):

The as of 2014 February work-in-progress v10 documentation has added detailed information on the possible `Method` options for `Eigenvalues`.  [See it here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues.html), under Details and Options, and also under Options.

I'm not sure how much of this applies to v9 as well because I haven't actually tried using all these options.

Comment: A bit surprising that Wolfram Research has posted such intimate details of the as-yet unreleased Mathematica 10. I believe pre-release testers of Wolfram products have to sign confidentiality agreements, and if somebody violates it, don't they have to kill him?

Comment: @murray if you query the version number on a raspberry it will tell you already v10.

Comment: @murray The documentation is online and public because a v10 beta [has already been released for the Raspberry Pi computer](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/) and it's freely available (!).  I haven't posted any information that wasn't already public.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Aha! I forgot about the Raspberry Pi beta.